# Can I install the wrong version of the software in Eclipse via the Install Software update site?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am not sure what version of Eclipse I have installed and I was told to work on Java projects I need to add the JDT. It says I can get this by going to the Install New Software window and entering the update site, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ and selecting Programming Languages > JDT.

My question is, what if I'm not using Galileo? I have found the JDT listed where it is supposed to as shown in the screen shot. Will it allow me to install incompatible software?

[image]

Comment: You should use the `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/xxx` site for your release. This will usually already by present in the 'Work with' list in Eclipse.

Comment: I do not know what my release is. How do I find that? Also, I do not see a Work with list any where.

Comment: On the Mac 'Eclipse > About Eclipse' will show you the release. 'Help > Install New Software' shows the Available Software dialog, click the down arrow on the 'Work with:' field to see the available sites list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flash Builder you have to go to About Flash Builder > click the Eclipse icon along the bottom (hover over the icon and the tool tip should say Eclipse.org). A window should open and in the feature name column look for, "Eclipse Platform" and that row will show the version number. It shows, "3.7.1.r37x_v2011. So now we know the version.

[image]

I proceeded to try and install JDT and it said a newer version was installed.